# VirtualHost resolvable from other machine, but not pingable

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost, ping

my VM has the IP `192.168.1.3`, the DNS-Server has `192.168.1.2`. In the `/etc/hosts`-file on the DNS-Server are the following entries

```
192.168.1.3 test.com
192.168.1.3 test.test.com
```

From command `nslookup test.com`/`nslookup test.test.com` (here obviously with `Name: test.test.com`) I get

```
Server:     192.168.1.2
Address:    192.168.1.2#53

Name:   test.com
Address: 192.168.2.3
```

But when I execute `ping test.test.com` it says: `ping: cannot resolve test.com: Unknown host`

The strange thing is that `ping test.test.com` is successful on the VM (`192.168.1.3`) and the DNS-Server (`192.168.1.2`).
Apache-Configtest returns `Syntax OK` and the VirtualHost-File has the right entries with `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` (in total two entries for the named domains)
I tried adding a subdomain to `test.com`, then it worked, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `nslookup` for DNS diagnostics, use `dig`.
(and the address returned by `nslookup` for test.com does not match what you say before)
`ping` uses the DNS, but your DNS server will not use the content of its `/etc/hosts` to reply to queries, it will just work as a normal caching recursive server, hence not finding your hosts.
If you want to resolve localnames, you either need to put them in all `/etc/hosts` files of all your servers (and make sure that `/etc/nsswitch.conf` do indeed list `files` for the `hosts` group), or have a local authoritative nameserver with your zone and make sure your clients will use it.